# CRM with web service

Tags: web-services, crm

I'm looking for a web based system where I can manage my company's partners,customize their profiles with additional information,manage their groups and communicate with this system by a third-party system via web services.its more like a light CRM.
Do you know any system with these descriptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I wouldn't characterize it as a "light" CRM, I believe that Microsoft Dynamics CRM meets all of these requirements.

Comment: Thansk for your answer.,In deed it may help, but Microsoft Dynamics CRM is too expensive. do you know others cheaper?

Comment: I know of other CRM systems, but can't tell you much of anything regarding their architecture or functionality.  Before you decide that Dynamics CRM is too expensive, it might be good to know the price. If you are a non-profit, a charitable organization, or a school, you may be able to get very preferential pricing.  Also, if your installation would be of significant size you may be able to get business incentives from Microsoft.  Good luck with your search.